# Disabling S3 Cache

Tags: caching, amazon-s3

I have static files located on Amazon S3, and am continually having issues with Amazon caching them. When I update/overwrite the static file, I'd love for it to automatically show the newest version rather than waiting...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way with S3 - it is designed to be eventually consistent, and does not do immediate commits.

Comment: Is that the case with all cdns?

Comment: No.  Even S3 can handle this now.

Comment: @chicks can be more specific please?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationAddingHeadersInS3

Answer (score 5):

you can set Cache-Control as Metadata on S3 using Bucket Explorer, or S3 Broswer.

here is the description https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationAddingHeadersInS3

Comment: [bucketexplorer.com](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/) is not available anymore. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationAddingHeadersInS3 to disable the cache of an object.

Answer (score 4):

Add to the parameters of putObject() or upload() the following:

```
CacheControl: "no-cache"
```

Comment: It's 'Cache-Control', also it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you always want the freshest file, you need to change the name.

Comment: Angular always generate a dist folder with an index.html file inside. Your suggestion is not practical I think. but thanks anyway...

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the Javascript SDK and was able to resolve the problem by setting `GetObject()`'s `ResponseCacheControl` parameter to `"no-cache"`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `Cache-Control: "no-cache`" doesn't work. I even checked and the metadata exists on the object I upload with a header each time, but it is still cached and shows the old image.

I think the only solution now is to generate a random 2 lenght string and append it to the end of your image name that you upload.

Comment: any update? im facing the same issue loading json files for i18n on my app

Comment: @Jesús Yes, adding a random generated string to the file name worked. 
For example: profile-pic-fr4.png, then you re-upload profile-pic-at3.png and the image will update.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [@Caleb Kock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987765/caleb-koch)  answer, it works for me:

```
const s3 = new S3Client({
    region,
    credentials: fromCognitoIdentityPool({
        identityPoolId: idPoolId,
        clientConfig: {region}
    }),
});

export const loadDebts = async () => {
    const command = new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: filename,
        ResponseCacheControl: "no-cache",
    });
    return s3.send(command)
        .then(response => response.Body.transformToString())
        .then(csv => parseCSV(csv))
        .then(debts => debts.map(debt => debt.toJson()))
}
```